# Backbone Json view template

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am just trying to get my head around backbone at the moment.

So i have the model, load the JSON file with the collection however i cant finger out the best way of displaying the array in the view to the underscore template.

I'm quite tired and seem to of gone through alot of tutorials, all with different ways of outputting this data through the view to the template. Is there a correct way of doing this? i'm guessing it should be looping with _.each? am i even on the correct path ? ;)

Please see code below.

Many thanks

```
<head>




</head>
<body>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.4.4/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.0.0/backbone.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">

        var News = Backbone.Model.extend();

        var Newscollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model: News,
            url: 'data.js'
        });

        var NewView = Backbone.View.extend({
            el: '#News',
            template: _.template($("#NewsTemplate").html()),

            render: function() {
                $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
                return this;
            }
        });


    </script>


    <div id="News"></div>


    <script id="NewsTemplate" type="text/template">
        <%= title %>
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: i dont see an array. the rest looks right

Comment: The data.js file that's called within the collection has a json array containing titles,names etc. Thanks :)

Comment: I'm not completely sure of what kind of answer your're looking for. I assumed some things and left an answer below. If that doesn't make sense, check out this tutorial: http://arturadib.com/hello-backbonejs/. It shows how you can make a view for your collection, and individual views for each of the models in the collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like to pass the collection to your template, you can do the following:

1: Define new collection in your view. Add some models to your collection. We'll define it as `this.collection`, and we'll assume there are multiple models in the collection by the time it gets rendered.

2: Pass the an object into the template. Make an object with 'collection' as the key and the JSON-ized collection (an array of models) as the value:

`$(this.el).html(this.template({'collection': this.collection.toJSON()}));`

3: Now, in the template, we can reference the collection by using `<%= collection %>`. However, I think you want to loop through the collection to render values. In your HTML template, you can create a loop using underscore's `_.each`:

```
    <ul>
    <% _.each(collection, function(item) { %>
        <li> <%= item.id %> : <%= item.title %> </li>
    <% }); %>
    </ul>
```

This will print a list of your models in the collection, assuming your models have an `id` and a `name` attribute.

Another, more 'backbone-ish' method of doing this would be to create a new view for each model in the collection, similar to the todo items in this tutorial: http://arturadib.com/hello-backbonejs/.